# How to check socket connection after every minute in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, sockets, visual-c++

I have implemented a design in C++ that is:-
I parse an XML file which contain the ip and port of several servers,for each ip and port i first call the connect to server function in which i make a TCP socket connection with the server whether the connection is established or not i make a thread for each ip and port,if connection is not established i send the status of the server that connection is not established and if connection is established i then make a request to the server and receive response from the server in the thread.This is done after every minute for each thread.
Now the problem that i am facing is,if connection terminates or if the server power goes,how to again make a connection i mean after every one minute before sending request and receiving response from the server i have to check whether the connection is still there or not.
Can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Having a thread per TCP/IP connection is the silliest design decision that anyone can make. Just so you know.

Comment: Vlad Lazarenko sir can you please tell how can i check for connection status?

Comment: @VladLazarenko - why?  Assuming that scaling is not an issue, one thread per connection is a trivial design effort, works fine, requires no state machine, (apart from the one you are given for free by the OS), and allows simple one-line-after-the-other coding of the handlers and the handlers can do whatever they wish, including making blocking calls.  I have been doing this silly thing for many years with no issues, both servers and clients.

Comment: @Martin James suppose the server closes after sending response and comes up after 2 mint,we can't use the same socket to send request to server with which we previously sent then do i have i to close thread using ExitThread() and connect to server again?

Comment: @MartinJames: How does it work well? It is a total waste of resources.  Puts pressure on scheduler, uses hell of a lot memory than ever needed for no good reason. Maybe easier to program, but hey — I don't want to upgrade to 16 cores Ivy Bridge with 32 GB of RAM because somebody doesn't know how to use async I/O properly. Which, after all, is not a lot harder than writing multi-threaded crap.

Answer (score 0):

You could have whatever it is that checks the connection status also do all of the communication for your other classes. Other classes pass a function pointer to it and in that method you test the connection, and if it's successful run the function you've been passed. If not stick it on a queue to be run once the connection is re-established.

Comment: @lan How to check the connection status thats the main cause sir.